# OmniAuth using google oauth 2 strategy scope failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm working on getting calendar data from google using **OmniAuth** and the **google-oauth-2** strategy.

If I put nothing into the scope field it works fine and I get the default info without the auth/failure message and I can use the app normally.

However the moment I add a scope, as in the example below, I get an "auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials".

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, ENV['TEST_KEY'], ENV['TEST_SECRET'], { :scope => 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' }
end
```

Is there something I'm missing or something I should change?

Comment: Omniauth is just for authentication. How do you get Calendar data after you get authentication tokens?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A quick e-mail from the google-oauth-2 strategy author pointed out the following:

If you don't include the profile scopes, it fails to authenticate.

By adding `userinfo.email` and `userinfo.profile` (along with the calendar scope) to the comma separated `:scope` list I was able to fix the problem.

Example:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, ENV['TEST_KEY'], ENV['TEST_SECRET'], 
           { :scope => 'userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' }
end
```

Comment: Odd, I keep getting this error: `Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email], invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/]}` Did you run into it?

Comment: Can you paste your :scope field?

Comment: Ugh. Finally got this working as well, except I still used commas but no spaces after the commas. If you take a look at the source (https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb#L22), it splits the string by commas. Sample that worked: `provider :google_oauth2, google_key, google_secret, {scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly", access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: ''}
`

Comment: you sure are a GENIUS 

It might be nice to add this for devise people ;)
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_KEY, GOOGLE_SECRET, :name => 'google', :scope => 'userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,calendar,calendar.readonly'

Comment: Hopefully the [readme will be updated](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/42)

Comment: @fholgado thank you sir, that is some spot. They really need to fix their docs.

Answer (score 11):

Funny, this didn't work for me.
I was able to make it work, removing the comma from the scope:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, ENV['TEST_KEY'], ENV['TEST_SECRET'], 
    { :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' }
end
```

Comment: This is what worked for me as well.  Remove commas and use full urls.  Thanks.